# How strong / sharp is Celestial Bronze

Tags: weapon, magical-items, percy-jackson, rick-riordan

In the Percy Jackson universe how Strong/Sharp is celestial bronze compared to mortal weapons? And is there a in universe example?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in the books to suggest that it's drastically *sharper* than normal metals but it does have some decidedly *odd* powers when wielded by a magical being such as a god or a demi-god.

**It doesn't cut humans.**

> The sword is celestial bronze. Forged by the Cyclopes, tempered in the
>   heart of Mount Etna, cooled in the River Lethe. It’s deadly to
>   monsters, to any creature from the Underworld, provided they don’t
>   kill you first. **But the blade will pass through mortals like an
>   illusion.** They simply are not important enough for the blade to kill.

**It's not unstoppable**

Percy tries to kill a Chimera. The blade glances off a rhinestone:

> Riptide was now a shining bronze blade in my hands, and as the Chimera
>   turned, **I slashed at its neck. That was my fatal mistake. The blade
>   sparked harmlessly off the dog collar.** I tried to regain my balance,
>   but I was so worried about defending myself against the fiery lion’s
>   mouth, I completely forgot about the serpent tail until it whipped
>   around and sank its fangs into my calf.

**But it can cut through wood, Celestial Bronze armour and thin pipe steel:**

> We fought through the hearth, kicking up coals and sparks. **Kronos slashed an armrest off the throne of Ares,** which was okay by me, but then he backed me up to my dad’s throne.
>   ‘Oh, yes,’ Kronos said. ‘This one will make fine kindling for my new hearth!’
>   Our blades clashed in a shower of sparks. He was stronger than me, but for the moment I felt the power of the ocean in my arms. **I pushed him back and struck again – slashing Riptide across his breastplate so hard I cut a gash in the celestial bronze.**

and

> Luke hacked downwards and I rolled behind a deckchair. I tried to stand, but my leg wouldn’t take the weight.
>   ‘Perrrrrcy!’ Grover bleated.
>   I rolled again as **Luke’s sword slashed the deckchair in half, metal pipes and all.**

Comment: well, idk about the question, but as far as @richard's answer, most of your examples are legit, but as for the last one, I remind you that throughout the series, luke wields Kronos' scythe in the form of a sword called backbiter, which was half Celestial bronze and half iron. It cannot be a factor in this discussion, because it is not bound by celestial bronze's limitations